# After forced push to heroku images on AWS S3 are not showing (403)

Tags: git, heroku, amazon-s3

I have been updating an app for a friend on heroku.
All the app and the heroku install had been set up by someone else.

So I cloned a repo with new code from github and did my updates.
Of course, pushing these changes needed to fail.
So I issued

```
git push -f production heroku_branch:master
```

where production:

```
[remote "production"]
    url = git@heroku.com:<our-app-name>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/production/*
```

This seemed to work but now all images are not being shown.
Images are on S3.
The browser says 403 for all images.
However, issuing

```
heroku config
```

confirms that the required vars are set (AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,S3_BUCKET_NAME)

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird, but after adding a bucket-policy it seems to work.
I am not sure this is all right, the heroku docs don't say anything about a bucket policy...and creating bucket policies is pretty cryptic! No like.

Also because the policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"AddPerm",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
         },
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Essentially granting access to anyone. Not sure if it needs to be that complicated to grant access to anyone? And maybe I am not even sure I want to grant access to anyone...but maybe it needs to be so? Otherwise how would people access images from a browser...

Too many questions here :(